# How to prevent touchmove event move the background using jquery /javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile, touchmove

Currently I am developing a website for ipad Safari

I used

```
addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, true);
```

to prevent the background moving when dragging the content. The problem is when I allow some element to drag

```
    addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { 
    //alert (e.target.id);
    if ( e.target.className != 'issues' && e.target.id != 'dialog' && e.target.id != 'issuesBox') 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
    }, true);
```

when I drag the element, it will drag the background too , how to fix this problem? I observe that this problem may caused by taphold ,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to prevent scroll on some element? Prevent default of both `touchstart` and `touchmove` events then. Here's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW24) from apple.

In my experience, prevent default on `touchstart` event is enough, e.g.,

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```